# Why does Kafka have a lot of Sensor objects in Old gen heap?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, heap-dump, g1gc

I have a Kafka broker (2.7.1) running on Java 11.
I noticed that the broker is slow because of the G1 old generation collections.
Taking a heap dump reveled that about 30% of heap is used by a `ConcurrentHashMap$Node` which retains 1000s of `org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Sensor` objects.

Why does Kafka keeps so many Sensor objects?

Looking at the Kafka log, I see that a Sensor is mentioned only twice.

```
INFO Created ConnectionAcceptRate sensor, quotaLimit=2147483647 (kafka.network.ConnectionQuotas)
INFO Created ConnectionAcceptRate-PLAINTEXT sensor, quotaLimit=2147483647 (kafka.network.ConnectionQuotas)
```

Is there a Kafka configuration that can change to reduce the amount of memory usage?

Comment: Kafka has lots of JMX metrics. Not sure about thousands https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/monitoring.html